# how to handle empty movie language in imdbpy using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, imdb, imdbpy

This is my code, but it gives me error for movies that don't have language.i don't know how to handle the error.

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
the_matrix = ia.get_movie(2234370)
the_matrix['language']
```

Error

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imdb\utils.py", line 1495, in __getitem__
    rawData = self.data[key]

KeyError: 'languages'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try` `except` to handle the error!

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
the_matrix = ia.get_movie(2234370)
try:
    the_matrix['language']
except KeyError as ke:
    print(str(ke))
```

or if it is a `dictionary` you can use this. the `get(Key, None)` method will return `None` if the key does not exists.

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
the_matrix = ia.get_movie(2234370)
the_matrix.get('language', None)
```